# Recursive VBA function not returning properly

Tags: excel, vba

Using this simple test below to a recursive function to understand why the function is not returning the expected value properly. here is the calling routine.

```
Public Sub TestRecursive()
   m_count = 0
   Debug.Print Recursive
End Sub
```

Here is the recursive function.

```
Private Function Recursive() As String
  Recursive = "start"
  m_count = m_count + 1
  If m_count < 5 Then

    'Debug.Print "counting " & CStr(m_count)
    Recursive
  Else

    'Debug.Print "ended count "
    Recursive = "ended"
    Exit Function
  End If
  'Debug.Print "should never reach here"
End Function
```

Not sure what is going on but the function recursive returns "start" instead of "ended". Any idea or suggestion what is going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned by zedfoxus, the reason you see the result you do is that your code does not utilise the return value of `Recursive`.  However, it is generally bad practice to use module scope variable unless really necessary.

This version avoids that

```
Option Explicit
Dim m_count As Long

Public Sub TestRecursive()
   m_count = 0
   Debug.Print Recursive
End Sub

Private Function Recursive() As String 
  Recursive = "start"
  m_count = m_count + 1
  If m_count < 5 Then

    'Debug.Print "counting " & CStr(m_count)
    Recursive = Recursive() ' <~~~ here's the change!
  Else

    'Debug.Print "ended count "
    Recursive = "ended"
    Exit Function
  End If
End Function
```

The same reasoning applies to the `m_count` variable too.  Here's a version that avoids that too.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestRecursive()
   Dim m_count As Long
   m_count = 0
   Debug.Print Recursive(m_count)
End Sub

Private Function Recursive(ByRef m_count As Long) As String
  Recursive = "start"
  m_count = m_count + 1
  If m_count < 5 Then

    'Debug.Print "counting " & CStr(m_count)
    Recursive = Recursive(m_count)
  Else

    'Debug.Print "ended count "
    Recursive = "ended"
    Exit Function
  End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, very interesting question regarding recursion. Here's what's happening when you call `Debug.Print Recursive`. That's when the first pass happens, designated below as [1]

```
[1] -> Recursion is "start" -> m_count is 1 -> calls second
[2] -> Recursion is "start" -> m_count is 2 -> calls third
[3] -> Recursion is "start" -> m_count is 3 -> calls fourth
[4] -> Recursion is "start" -> m_count is 4 -> calls fifth
[5] -> Recursion is "start" -> m_count is 5 -> Recursion is  "end" -> returns to 4
[4] -> doesn't do anything with returned value -> returns "start" to 3
[3] -> doesn't do anything with returned value -> returns "start" to 2 and so on
```

Therefore you see `start` printed.

Here's a slightly modified version that helps print `ended`.

```
' make global variables that will remember information
Option Explicit
Dim m_count As Integer
Dim m_finalword As String

Public Sub TestRecursive()
   m_count = 0
   Recursive  ' run recursive here 
   Debug.Print m_finalword
End Sub

Private Function Recursive() As String
  Recursive = "start"
  m_count = m_count + 1
  If m_count < 5 Then
    m_finalword = Recursive ' remember Recursive's value in m_finalword
    Recursive               ' run recursive again because our count is below 5
  Else
    m_finalword = "ended"   ' if count went above 5, no need to do recursion
    Exit Function           ' just set m_finalword's value and exit to parent
  End If
End Function
```

You should check out debugging and setting breakpoints in VBA. It will tremendously help in the future in debugging situations like this.

Comment: Thanks either solution presented returns the proper value now. Adding some debug.print statements, the recursive routines continues to call itself after the exit function                                                            counting 1
counting 2
counting 3
counting 4
ended count at 5
**should never reach here 5**
**should never reach here 5**
**should never reach here 5**
**should never reach here 5**
ended. any idea why?

Comment: Glad to know that the solutions provide proper values. Chris's answer is much better than mine since he avoids using globals. If you feel that either answer gave you the solution you desired, please feel free to mark one answer as accepted to give closer to your question.