# How to properly define interconnected recursive sub routines with option explicit in VBA?

Tags: vba, recursion, nested

I found out that VBA doesn't like nesting sub routines after I have done the following code and now I don't know how to define the sub routines outside of each other while respecting the Option Explicit statement, and properly calling other sub routines within each other while also respecting the counter for the stack overflow prevention on the recursive calls.

```
Option Explicit
Sub OuterSub(counter As Integer)
    ' Code
    
    Sub InnerSubA(rng As Range, prompt As String)
        'Code
        ' Run outersub recursively
        OuterSub (counter + 1) ' Counter to prevent stack overflow
        'Code
    End Sub
    
    ' Code
    ' Run 1st Inner sub
    InnerSubA rng, prompt
    ' Code
    
    Sub InnerSubB(counter As Integer)
        ' Code
        ' Recursively call itself
        InnerSubB (counter + 1) ' Counter to prevent stack overflow
        ' Code
        ' Run InnerSubA
        InnerSubA rng, prompt
        'Code
    End Sub
    
    ' Run 2nd Inner Sub
    InnerSubB 0
    
    'Code
    
End Sub

Sub main()
    ' Run OuterSub
    OuterSub 0
End Sub
```

I have tried defining the inner subs outside the outer sub but realized that it might not work because I want to respect the Option Explicit statement and that since the inner sub calls the outer sub and vise versa, I don't know which order I should define them. It's a bit like the chicken or the egg situation. Furthermore, the counters incremented on the recursive calls and I am not sure how to maintain them if the definitions of the inner subs are outside.

Comment: VBA does not support nesting Sub definitions like that. Are you maybe thinking of a Class?

Comment: No, not a class. Thanks though.

Comment: Use Module/Form level variables to share them between Subs.  Use Public/Global variables to share them between Modules/Forms. The way you have it set up simply will not work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33162030/recursive-vba-function-not-returning-properly